# Lookup value from another matrix

Tags: r

I have a stepwise structure of tariffs for treatments. Treatment between 0-33 hrs receive the tariff $96. Treatments between 34 and 96 hours receive 224, etc.

I would like to create graph with treatment hours and tariffs with the hrs on the x-axis and tariff on y-axis. In order to do that I need to create a variable that gives me the corresponding tariff for each treatment hour ('hr'). How do I do this in R?

```
min <- c(381, 201, 97, 34, 0)
max <- c(NA, 380, 200, 96, 33)
tariff2019 <- c(779, 536, 368, 224, 96)

dat <- data.frame(hr=seq(401))
dat$tariff <-
```

Comment: What do you want the plot to look like? Lines? Bars? Lots of dots? All connected? Different colors?

Comment: @GregorThomas Lines, thanks.

Comment: `plot(rev(min), rev(tariff2019), type = "s")`

Comment: Thanks. That's easier than I thought.